# F# Debugging and code maintenance: Is there an un-factoring, factoring tool for F#?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

When working down a long chain of factored F# code there are times I have to un-factor the code for various reasons so I can modify the code to fix a bug or add a change, followed by factoring the code again.

Since un-factoring and factoring are for the most part symbolic transformations which should be able to be automated, (I know it's not easy in reality); has anyone made such a tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know of any tools like that, i am assuming that you are asking about breaking up the pipes so that you can put a break point somewhere and inspect the result. I agree that it's the hardest part of working with code in F#, that once you've composed it, it's virtually impossible to step through it with all the lazy evaluation and compositions.

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm having problems relating F# and it's debugging capabilities. I have it here http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4401812 but in summary, I cannot even see locals, or place the cursor over a variable and see its value. Any clues? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this, it can be useful to override the forward pipe operator, which allows you to put a breakpoint on it.  Doesn't necessarily solve the lazy/composition issues but a useful trick anyway.

Details here:

http://www.kiteason.com/blogengine/post/2012/09/13/Tapping-into-the-pipe.aspx